# Saving partial data with Angularfire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Hi I have a setup with angular gridster and angular chartjs where the block locations and charts are generated from Firebase data.

something like this

```
<div gridster-item="widget" ng-repeat="widget in widgets" ng-init="getTheData(widget)">
    <canvas id="line-gridster" class="chart-base" chart-type="widget.type" data="widget.data" labels="widget.labels" legend="false" series="widget.series" ></canvas>
</div>
```

And in the controller

```
var fire = new Firebase(FIREURL);
$scope.widgets = $firebaseArray(fire)


var getChart = {

    a: function(days){
        return aChartFactory.createChartData(days);
    },
    u: function(days){
        return uChartFactory.createChartData(days);
    },

}


$scope.getTheData = function(widget){

    getChart[widget.data](widget.time).then(function(data){

        widget.data = data[1];
        widget.labels = data[0];
        widget.series = data[2];

    });

};
```

The initial data of a widget looks like this

```
widget.$id {
    row: 1,
    col: 2,
    sizeX: 2,
    sizeY: 2,
    type: 'bar',
    labels: 'labels',
    data: 'a',
    series: 'series',
    time: 30
}
```

the factories inside getChart is just for generating chartdata.

The problem I'm having is when I'm trying to save the location of moved blocks from gridster.

because serveral blocks can have new rows and cols by moving a block I tried wrapping $scope.widgets.$save in a forEach function.

And the new block positions are saved fine but so is the generated chartdata widget.data, widget.labels and widget.series.

So my initial settings are replaced which means now the charts are static instead..

I tried putting child().set inside of the foreEach instead to save just the required attributes but that doesn't seem to work.
I guess it's because I can't do the loop on the firebase ref, only the array, where I can't do .set

Is there any other way I could set only specific attributes on all items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AngularFire does not have a method to update only part of an object. But since AngularFire is built on top of Firebase's JavaScript SDK, you have access to all of the goodness that offers. That means you can use the `Firebase.update()` method, which will only update the properties you specify.

If you have a `$firebaseObject`, you can update some properties with:

```
object.$ref().update({ key1: 'newValue1', key7: 'newValue2' });
```

Comment: Ok i will try it, so maybe a get record by id on all the blocks and then your example?